# What makes a function of a matrix convex?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, convex-analysis

When is the function of a matrix convex?

The function: $f(x) = x^T  z + x^T  \Sigma  x $

$\Sigma$ is a $N \times N$ matrix and $x$ and $z$ are $N \times 1$ vectors.

I've been able to differentiate the function twice and arrived at $2\Sigma$. I am now wondering how I would be able to know which type of matrices would make the original function convex?

Comment: why do you call $f$ a 'function of a matrix'?

Comment: The matrix sigma is a term in the function and its derivatives.

Comment: $f$ is a function of $x$? In any event, being convex just means that the epigraph is convex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you've written is not a function of a matrix (even though it is written in terms of a matrix) unless you consider vectors as matrices.

To answer your second question, $\Sigma$ must be positive semidefinite so that the hessian has only nonnegative eigenvalues and thus only positive curvature and thus is convex.